# I can't log into Minecraft Launcher nor minecraft.net on my Mac

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I got Minecraft on July 2, 2019. I put in the code, entered the username and password, and logged into minecraft.net.

Once I put in my email and password, it says "Invalid username or password." I tried waiting for a while but the output remains. I tried my HP laptop and it worked somehow, but on the Mac it doesn't work.

I know that my username should be my email, but it still doesn't work. I've waited for 1-2 days now, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: You might have scripts or firewalls blocking the attempt, can you check?